# Splitted data, reading from Java InputStream

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, inputstream

I'm using the [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) Java class for managing incoming data from bluetooth RFCOMM channel, with Android device.

I use the following code, inside a Thread, always listening for incoming data:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

while (true) {
    try {
        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

        byte[] payload = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, bytes);
        Packet p = new Packet(payload);

        managePacket(p); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Each packet received from the remote device, is organized in block of size 254 byte. So what I really read is:

```
SEND PACKET 1 -> received 254 bytes (OK)
SEND PACKET 2 -> received 254 bytes (OK)
SEND PACKET 3 -> received 254 bytes (OK)
SEND PACKET 4 -> received 254 bytes (OK)
SEND PACKET 5 -> received   8 bytes (ERROR)
              -> received 246 bytes (ERROR)
```

So the first four packet are read fine, but the fifth packet il splitted in two different read (8 bytes + 246 bytes).

It seems that after the stream read 1024 bytes (254 + 254 + 254 + 254 + 8 = 1024) it needs to stop the read and restart a new one.

**NOTE:** I can't wait for reveiving 254 byte before process the packet, since the protocol can provide also different size packet.

Comment: It looks like you will need, either to read a full packet (`DataInputStream#readFully()` will block until the specified length is reach), or read each byte/char and rebuild the packet yourself before sending it.

Comment: This means that I can read correctly the packet if I don't know the exact length, right?